# FFprobeKit command not showing the specific error when it fails to execute

Tags: android, react-native, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm getting the video duration of a video in react native by using [FFMpegkit library](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native) and by running bellow code

```
const getVideoDuration = async (uri: string): Promise<void> => {
      try {
      await FFprobeKit.executeAsync(
        `-v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 ${uri}`,
      ).then(async information => {
        const failStackTrace = await information.getFailStackTrace();
        console.log(failStackTrace);
        await information.getOutput().then(output => {
          const value = parseFloat(output.toString());
          const time = value * 1000;
          setInputVideoDuration(time);
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

**The issue is that the the code isn't executing sometimes**. And it's like **sporadic**. I want to trigger the exact error given when failing this code. The exact error is not given by the library logs but it produce other command executing logs. Is there any way to get the exact error or the exception?

Currently the error shows like this in the logs but it doesn't have any information. also failStackTrace isn't producing any logs either

```
 libswscale      6.  1.102 /  6.  1.102
 LOG    libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
 LOG  ReturnCode.ERROR
```

Comment: There probably isn't an error per se. Some codecs do not store duration info, so there is no duration for ffprobe to return (thus error returncode). You just need to report missing duration info. (Look around, there is a way to find the actual duration in those cases by reading packet info.)